# Does ls try to access subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix

I am trying to learn about file permissions in UNIX. I am using a terminal with Ubuntu 18.10. Let's say my home directory contains `test/test1/test2`.

I `cd test` and then type `chmod a=r *`. Then when I type `cd test1` I get `bash: cd: test1: Permission denied`. Good, that's what's supposed to happen.

However when I type `ls test1` I get `ls: cannot access 'test1/test2': Permission denied` and in the next line `test2`.

Can someone explain to a newbie like me why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought it was more a bash question than a linux one and as such presumed it was ok for here.

Comment: It's actually more of an `ls` question, I would say. You are using GNU coreutils `ls`, I am using BSD `ls`, and you are using an OS that sets `$LS_COLORS` and has a default `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` (or something like that), whereas mine doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `r`ead permission to `test1`, therefore you are allowed to read its contents. (A directory is simply a file that lists its contents, just like a directory in the real world.) So, it is perfectly normal that you get `test2` listed.

However, you don't have enter (`x`) permissions for `test1`, so you cannot enter the directory to look at its contents. Therefore, you only know that a file named `test2` exists, but you don't know what it is.

On many operating systems, the default for `ls` when used interactively, is to use different colors to distinguish between different kinds of files, therefore `ls` will try to access `test1/test2` so that it can print it with the correct color, but since you don't have enter permissions for `test1`, this will fail.

On my operating system, `ls` is set by default to not print any colors or other indicators, therefore, I simply get `test2` without any errors. Conversely, if I add any options that require entering `test1`, my `ls` will actually not print anything at all!